# Numpy: How to locate matrix value using known X and Y values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm fairly new to Python and need some assistance regarding the use of `numpy.where`.

I have created 2 vectors with 33 values in each (range -4 to 4), then made two 2D (x and y) matrices 33x33 out of those vectors using `np.meshgrid`. Next,  I created a matrix `Z` with the function `Z=sin(sqrt(X^2+Y^2))`.

I should now find the value from that matrix `Z` where `x`=0.5 and `y`=-0.5 by using `numpy.where`, but I cant get it to work, help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hi, can you share the code in the question itself (not in comments)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are really looking for is the `np.logical_and()` function. [Docs here.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html)

In your example:

```
import numpy as np

v = np.linspace(-4, 4, 33)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(v, v)
Z = np.sin(np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2))
```

... to find the point in `Z` where `X` is 0.5 and `Y` is -0.5, you can use:

```
Z[np.logical_and(X==0.5, Y==-0.5)]
```

Output:

```
array([0.64963694])
```

Graph example:

As can be seen in the graph below, the `Z` axis value is confirmed as shown in the output above.

[image]

Comments:

The `numpy.where()` function is (generally) used for conditional testing. For example, 'If `X==0.5`, then do `thing1`, else do `thing2`'.  It appears that this is not what you're trying to do; but rather to locate a value in the `Z` matrix where `X==n` **and** `Y==m` - hence the use of the `logical_and()` function.